# Tory Bruno mentioned "unsolvable combustion instability" of "large methane engines". What, why, how?

Tags: engine-design, combustion, methalox

Relevant tweet, an hour ago: https://twitter.com/torybruno/status/1405210138189864960?s=19

> **a Tweeted Question:** Why wasn't methane used in the 2000s, when it was readily available unlike the time leading up to it?
>
> **Bruno:** Prior attempts at a large Methane rocket engine failed due to ***unsolvable combustion instability*** (emphasis added)

What previous attempts at building large methane engines were unsuccessful prior to the Raptor/BE-4s due to said unsolvable combustion instabilities?

Further, why were such combustion instabilities unique to methalox cycles?

Finally, how were these unsolvable instabilities solved so completely that SpaceX and ULA are betting their futures on CH4 engines?

Comment: I see nothing in the tweet you linked that supports the statement you are asking about. All Tory Bruno is saying is that a) there was a project to build a large methalox engine, and b) that project had problems with combustion instabilities. He is not saying that the combustion instabilities had anything to do with the "methalox" part of the engine, nor with the "large" part for that matter. It could just as well have been the case that the particular project he is talking about chose a bad geometry of the combustion chamber or had problems with the manufacturing tolerances of their injectors.